# Loss decreasing with each epoch but the accuracy is zero

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to predict the product a customer will redeem using a table like the one below:

|  | id_customer | product_name | item_quantity | product_name_index | product_category_index | product_category | product_type | seller_name |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1234 | tv | 1 | 40391 | 212 | eletronics | 4 | 3 |  |
|  | 12345 | smart tv | 1 | 16347 | 212 | eletronics | 4 | 5 |  |
|  | 123456 | tv | 1 | 40391 | 212 | eletronics | 4 | 3 |  |
|  | 1234567 | security camera | 1 | 1449 | 29 | eletronics | 2 | 6 |  |
|  | 12345678 | soda | 1 | 37969 | 174 | food | 3 | 38 |  |

My model is decreasing losses however, unfortunately, the accuracy is not correct:

> Epoch 2/15
> 114/114 [==============================] - 4s 26ms/step - loss: 83.7829 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 54.7766 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
>
> Epoch 2/15
> 114/114 [==============================] - 3s 24ms/step - loss: 54.5661 - accuracy: >0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 54.7244 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

The code below demonstrates how I am assembling the model.
Please is there any suggestion on how I should change it so that the predictions are correct?

```
embedding_size = 50
min_redemption = min(df_filtered['product_category_index'].value_counts())
max_redemption = max(df_filtered['product_category_index'].value_counts())

num_customers = len(df_filtered['id_customer'].drop_duplicates())
num_products = len(df_filtered['product_category_index'].drop_duplicates())


df = df_filtered.sample(frac=1, random_state=42)
X  = df.drop(['product_category_index'],axis=1)
y  = df['product_category_index']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state = 0)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

class RecommenderNet(Model):
    def __init__(self, num_customers, num_products, embedding_size, **kwargs):
        super(RecommenderNet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_customers = num_customers
        self.num_products = num_products
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.customer_embedding = Embedding(
            num_customers,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=l2(1e-6),
        )
        self.customer_bias = Embedding(num_customers, 1)
        self.product_embedding = Embedding(
            num_products,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=l2(1e-6),
        )
        self.product_bias = Embedding(num_products, 1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        customer_vector = self.customer_embedding(inputs[:, 0])
        customer_bias = self.customer_bias(inputs[:, 0])
        product_vector = self.product_embedding(inputs[:, 1])
        product_bias = self.product_bias(inputs[:, 1])
        dot_customer_product = tensordot(customer_vector, product_vector, 2)
        # Add all the components (including bias)
        x = dot_customer_product + customer_bias + product_bias

        return relu(x)

model = RecommenderNet(num_customers,num_products, embedding_size)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy')code here``
```

Comment: Are you sure accuracy is the right metric?

Comment: You have loss as "mae" -- a regression loss and metric as "accuracy" -- a classification loss.

Comment: well, mean absolute error is used for continuous values. so are you sure that accuracy is the right metric for your problem as per @M.Innat saying?

Comment: Hi @UesleiSutil,  A regression model can only predict values that are lower or higher than the actual value. As a result, the only way to determine the model’s accuracy is through residuals. Residuals are the difference between the actual and predicted values. You can think of residuals as being a distance. So, the closer the residual is to zero, the better our model performs in making its predictions. Thank You.